# How Binding SortedDicionary<Timespan, List<Class>> storage with Listbox, MVVM Pattern?

Tags: c#, mvvm, binding

I'm newbie MVVM Pattern on C#.
I'm trying Binding variable into WPF xaml, with MVVM Pattern.
In xaml, I'm trying with Listbox Element.

Binding Object is This :

```
public SortedDictionary <TimeSpan, List<circles>> storage;
```

And, class circles has :

```
int ID;
int Position_X;
int Position_Y;
string Circle_Color;
```

So, Structure of storage will be like this :

```
00:00:001 - 1, 100, 200, White
          - 2, 200, 300, Black
          - 3, 100, 150, Blue
00:00:020 - 1, 111, 222, Red
```

And, Structure of Solution File is like this :

```
[Folder] - [File]
Models - Storage
ViewModels - MainViewModel.cs
           - FrameSelectorViewModel.cs
           - VideoControlViewModel.cs
Views - MainWindow.xaml
      - FrameSelector.xaml
      - VideoControl.xml
```

So, Each xaml will be binded with ViewModel Class.

And storage variable is in FrameSelectorViewModel Class.
And, I want to display on FrameSelector View on Hiericaly.
But, It wasn't work.

simply, I tried this code on FrameSelector.xaml file.

```
<ComboBox Margin="0,5" ItemsSource="{Binding storage}">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>
```

in Debug Mode, variable storage was in , but not displayed.

Is there any answer for me?

Thanks read this ! :0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you can only bind Properties, currently you have declared variables
2. all the ViewModels need to implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://ensystem.compontmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netcore-3.1) interface to ensure, that the UI get's triggered to Update itself.
3. Be aware, that XAML is case sensitive, PropertyNames must exact match the name in the Viewmodel. You bind  your TextBlock to 'Key' but there is no such Prop ('ID' perhaps)?
4. Use `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of `List<T>`, they notify the UI if elements are added, or removed
5. Instead of a Dictionary you may use an `ObservableCollection<MyPairs>` with

   ```
   class MyPairs //don't forget INotifyPropertyChanged if data changes on runtime
   {
     public TimeSpan Time {get;set;}
     public ObservableCollection<circles> circles {get;set;}
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks answering my question! I'll try it ! :)